# SplitLayoutPanel - how to set minimum size to center widget

Tags: gwt

I split page on two parts. One center and one south. I want to set minimum size to both of them. But method setMinimumSize is working only with non-center widgets. Could you tell me if there is any possibility to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue identified in GWT2.0. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4731) you can see here more about it.

Comment: Is there some kind of workaround ? It seems to be an old issue, will this ever be fixed ?